# Need only the last few items from each row in a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, split

I have a CSV file (using `';'` as the separator).  I have used a `StreamReader` to read in each line of the file. The file contains almost 4000 rows and each row has 16 columns.  I only need the last 5 numbers from each row, but I am unsure as to how to split each row and get only the last 5 numbers.

Example data:

> 2002;10;;0;0 EUR;122;448 823 EUR;8315;6 973 EUR;192233;586 EUR;6;13;55;66;81
>   2002;9;;0;0 EUR;62;750 138 EUR;4784;10 294 EUR;137390;697 EUR;13;51;55;62;74
>   2002;8;;0;0 EUR;56;801 650 EUR;6377;7 454 EUR;177197;522 EUR;12;13;19;28;85

So for the first row, the data I actually need is `{ 6; 13; 55; 66; 81 }`

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
foreach(var line in file)
{
    var result = test.Split(';');
    var last = result.Length-1;
    var first = result[last-4];
    var second = result[last-3];
    var third = result[last-2];
    var fourth = result[last-1];
    var fifth = result[last];
}
```

As a side note, a library that I have found very helpful when dealing with CSV files is [LINQtoCSV](https://github.com/mperdeck/LINQtoCSV).  There is a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToCsv/) package available so it can be easily added to a project.  If you are going to have to do anything else with this data, you may want to check it out.

**Edit:**
Here is an example of doing this with LINQtoCSV.  If you read the documentation they show how to set up a more strongly typed class that you could read into, for simplicity here I am just doing it in a raw fashion.

```
// Define the class for reading, both IDataRow and DataRowItem
// are part of the LINQtoCSV namespace
public class MyRow : List<DataRowItem>, IDataRow
{
}

// Create the context, the file description and then read the file.
var context = new CsvContext();
var inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
{
    SeparatorChar = ';',
    FirstLineHasColumnNames = false, // Change this if yours does
};

// Note: You don't need to use your stream reader, just use the LINQtoCSV
// Read method to load the data into an IEnumerable. You can read the
// documentation for more information and options on loading/reading the
// data.
var products = context.Read<MyRow>(@"yourfile.csv", inputFileDescription);

// Iterate all the rows and grab the last 5 items from the row
foreach (var row in products)
{
    var last = row.Count - 1;
    var first = row[last - 4];
    var second = row[last - 3];
    var third = row[last - 2];
    var fourth = row[last - 1];
    var fifth = row[last];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing the part of the logic as per the example you provided. This would split one entire row and return you the last five numbers in an array.

```
string row = "2002; 10; ; 0; 0 EUR; 122; 448 823 EUR; 8315; 6 973 EUR; 192233; 586 EUR; 6; 13; 55; 66; 81";
string[] rowArray = row.Trim().Split(';');
string[] numbers = rowArray.Skip(Math.Max(0, rowArray.Length - 5)).ToArray();
```

`numbers` would contain all the last five numbers you want which you can access with the indexes- `numbers[0], numbers[1],` and so on.. upto `numbers[4]`.

*Note:* You have to split the data as read from the `StreamReader` into rows. You you get the rows, loop through each row and use the above three lines of code to get the last five numbers.

Comment: @SventekKornéliaCsilla You have to accept one of the answers posted here which answers/solves your problem closely.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) library, to parse the file and access the last 5 members as below

```
foreach (dynamic rec in new ChoCSVReader("quotes.csv").WithDelimiter(";"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", rec[11]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", rec[12]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", rec[13]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", rec[14]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", rec[15]);
}
```